# In Objective-C, is there an elegant way to forward the entire input of a NSFileHandle object to another NSFileHandle object ? Perhaps handlers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am working on a networking application for macOS in Objective-C. I have to somehow filter the input of a NSFileHandle object and forward it to another NSFileHandle object. Just to start with something to learn, I would like to forward the entire object 1 input to object 2 output. Is there a clean way, which has also to be fast given it handles network packets directly ? While I wait for possible answers, I believe the best would be to read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW2) document very carefully. I believe it allows to perform this task at the lowest level so with great speed, but it mentions technologies I am not very familiar with, especially the Core Foundation APIs. I am not forced to use NSFileHandle, I start with socket descriptors so I believe I can use any of the mentioned APIs. My only concern is that what I need is a simple way to detect that there is available data on the socket, since I have to coordinate with some existing codebase that uses:

```
ssize_t actual = ::read(fileDescriptor, buffer.data(), mtu);
```

To read directly from the socket when there is available data. I have tried to put the above code inside a readability handler of a NSFileHandle instantiated with the socket descriptor, which is a little hacky since the proper way would be to call [handle availableData] in the readability handler, but this is the best I came up with. I receive all the data reading from the socket, then I write to the output using ::sendto which returns a meaningful size value, but the packets are not working as they should. I really don't know why for the moment.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

After learning from the accepted answer, I came out with the following code:

```
- (void)monitorSocket:(uintptr_t)fileDescriptor {

      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

      dispatch_source_t readSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, fileDescriptor, 0, queue);

     if(!readSource) {
         // handle error
         NSLog(@"Handle error");
     } else {
          self.theSource = readSource;
     }

// Install the event handler
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(readSource, ^{
    size_t estimated = dispatch_source_get_data(readSource);
    // No data
    if(estimated == 0) {
        
        NSLog(@"Here we are.");
        
        return;
    }
    
    BOOL done = NO;
    
    void *buffer2 = malloc(estimated);
    if(buffer2) {
                    
        const int mtu = self.currentTunnel.mtu;
        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(mtu);
        buffer.resize(mtu);
        
        ssize_t actual = ::read(fileDescriptor, buffer.data(), mtu);
     
        buffer.resize(actual);
        
        if(actual == -1)
        {
            qWarning() << "Unable to read from split tunnel device:" << "ErrnoTracer{errno}";
            return;
        }
        
        // First 4 bytes indicate address family (IPv4 or IPv6)
        int addressFamily = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<int *>(buffer.data()));
        
        switch(addressFamily)
        {
            case AF_INET: {
                ssize_t effective = [self handleIp4:std::move(buffer) actualSize:actual socketDescriptor:self.currentTunnel._rawFd4];
                if (effective == (actual - 4)) {
                    done = YES;
                }
                break;
            }
            case AF_INET6:
                //handleIp6(std::move(buffer), actual);
                break;
            default:
                qWarning() << "Unsupported address family:" << addressFamily;
        }
        free(buffer2);
        
        // If there is no more data, cancel the source.
        if(done) {
            dispatch_source_cancel(readSource);
        }
        
    }
});

// Install the cancellation handler
// (close may not be appropriate for your use case)
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(readSource, ^{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self monitorSocket:fileDescriptor];
    });
});

// Start reading
dispatch_resume(readSource);

// Keep a reference to readSource until it's no longer needed
 
}

- (ssize_t)handleIp4:(std::vector<unsigned char>)buffer actualSize:                                            (ssize_t)actualSize socketDescriptor:(int)socketDescriptor
   {
      // skip the first 4 bytes (it stores AF_NET)
      auto pPacket = Packet::createFromData(std::move(buffer), 4);
      if(!pPacket)
    {
        qWarning() << "Packet is invalid; read" << actualSize <<     "bytes from stun";
        return 0;
     }

//    PidFinder bypassFinder{_excludedApps};
//    PidFinder vpnOnlyFinder{_vpnOnlyApps};
//    PiaConnections piaConnections{Path::ExecutableDir, this};

// Update the cache for non-split apps, to keep track of the ports we care about
// when generating firewall rules
// _defaultAppsCache.refresh(IPv4);

// Get ports for our tracked apps
//  auto bypassPorts = bypassFinder.ports(bypassFinder.pids(), PidFinder::IPv4);
// auto vpnOnlyPorts = vpnOnlyFinder.ports(vpnOnlyFinder.pids(), PidFinder::IPv4);
// auto defaultPorts = _defaultAppsCache.ports(IPv4);

// These packets seem to have protocol 255, so drop them
if(pPacket->packetType() == Packet::Other)
    return 0;

// Update with our pia-specific connections
//   bypassPorts += piaConnections.bypassPorts();
//   vpnOnlyPorts += piaConnections.vpnOnlyPorts();

//    // Drop vpnOnly packets when not connected
//    if(!_params.isConnected && pPacket->sourcePort() && vpnOnlyPorts.contains(pPacket->sourcePort()))
//    {
//        qInfo() << "Dropping an Ipv4 vpnOnly packet";
//        return;
//    }

// We only add a (non-split) app cache entry if the port wasn't associated with
// a bypass or vpnonly app
//    if(pPacket->packetType() != Packet::Other && !isSplitPort(pPacket->sourcePort(), bypassPorts, vpnOnlyPorts))
//    {
//        pid_t newPid = bypassFinder.pidForPort(pPacket->sourcePort(), PidFinder::IPv4);
//        if(newPid)
//            _defaultAppsCache.addEntry(IPv4, newPid, pPacket->sourcePort());
//        else
//            // We could not find an associated PID for the packet, so drop it.
//            // We drop a packet by just returning since a packet only goes further if it's re-injected
//            return;
//    }

// Drop multicast/broadcast and self-addressed packets
const auto destAddress = QHostAddress { pPacket->destAddress() };
// Drop multicast/broadcast and self-addressed packets

if(destAddress.isMulticast() || destAddress.isBroadcast() || [destAddress.toString().toNSString() isEqualToString:self.currentTunnel.splitTunnelIP.ipv4AddressString]) {
    return 0; // We drop a packet by just returning
}
bool conversionOK = false;
QHostAddress ip4Address(destAddress.toIPv4Address(&conversionOK));
QString ip4String;
if (conversionOK)
{
    ip4String = ip4Address.toString();
}

NSString *test = ip4String.toNSString();

NSLog(@"Destination Address is %@",test);

if (![test isEqualToString:@"147.75.47.199"]) {
    return 0;
}

const AddressPair newPacketAddress{pPacket->sourceAddress(), pPacket->sourcePort()};

if(self._lastPacketAddress4 == newPacketAddress)
    ++self._lastPacketCount4;
else
    self._lastPacketCount4 = 0;

if(self._lastPacketCount4 > 10)
{
    qInfo() << "Received repeated packet (10 times), dropping" << pPacket->toString();
    return 0;
}

// Prevent default traffic when KS=always and disconnected
// All other traffic is fine - vpnOnly is blocked anyway and bypass is allowed
//    if(_params.blockAll && !_params.isConnected)
//        defaultPorts.clear();

//_defaultRuleUpdater.update(IPv4, defaultPorts);
//_bypassRuleUpdater.update(IPv4, bypassPorts);
//_vpnOnlyRuleUpdater.update(IPv4, vpnOnlyPorts);

self._lastPacketAddress4 = newPacketAddress;

qInfo() << "Re-injecting IPv4 packet:" << pPacket->toString();

// Re-inject the packet
struct sockaddr_in to{};
to.sin_family = AF_INET;
to.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(pPacket->destAddress());

ssize_t effectiveTransmittedSize = ::sendto(socketDescriptor, pPacket->toRaw(), pPacket->len() , 0, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&to), sizeof(to));

NSLog(@"Eccoci");

if(effectiveTransmittedSize == -1)
{
    qWarning() << "Unable to reinject packet" << pPacket->toString() << "-"
    << "ErrnoTracer{errno}";
    qWarning() << "Packet -" << pPacket->len() << "bytes";
    std::uint32_t *pPktWords = reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(pPacket->toRaw());
    for(int i=0; i+4 <= pPacket->len(); i += 4)
    {
        qWarning() << QString::asprintf("%03d", i) << QString::asprintf("%08X", pPktWords[i/4]);
    }
    if(pPacket->len() % 4)
    {
        std::uint8_t *pTailBytes = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(pPacket->toRaw());
        unsigned lastWordOffset = pPacket->len() / 4;
        pTailBytes += lastWordOffset * 4;
        std::uint32_t lastWord = 0;
        lastWord |= pTailBytes[0];
        lastWord <<= 8;
        if(pPacket->len() % 4 >= 2)
            lastWord |= pTailBytes[1];
        lastWord <<= 8;
        if(pPacket->len() % 4 >= 3)
            lastWord |= pTailBytes[2];
        lastWord <<= 8;
        qWarning() << QString::asprintf("%03d", lastWordOffset*4) << QString::asprintf("%08X", lastWord);
    }
} else {
    NSBeep();
    return effectiveTransmittedSize;
}

return 0;
}
```

This is the first version of a port of a C++ Qt project, and my goal for the moment is to establish the stun device, then curl 147.75.47.199 and obtain my public IP back. This is the reason why aa lot of code is commented for the moment. Thanks a lot for helping me, really appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using a file descriptor dispatch source?

Comment: I will edit my question, but could you please explain how to do so ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not forced to use `NSFileHandle` one option is a file descriptor [read dispatch source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW22):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_source_t readSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, fd, 0, queue);
if(!readSource) {
  // handle error
}
 
// Install the event handler
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(readSource, ^{
  size_t estimated = dispatch_source_get_data(readSource);

  // If estimated is 0 malloc may return NULL which is not an error
  void *buffer = malloc(estimated);
  if(!buffer && estimated > 0) {
    // handle error
  }

  ssize_t actual = read(fd, buffer, estimated);

  // Process/send the data
  BOOL done = MyProcessData(buffer, actual);
 
  free(buffer);
 
  // If there is no more data, cancel the source.
  if(done)
    dispatch_source_cancel(readSource);
  }
});
 
// Install the cancellation handler
// (close may not be appropriate for your use case)
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(readSource, ^{close(fd);});
 
// Start reading
dispatch_resume(readSource);

// Keep a reference to readSource until it's no longer needed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, outstanding answer. I tried something similar, but forgot to keep a reference and the handler never fired. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sbooth, thanks again, I wanted to ask you, should I somehow empty my buffer ? The packets seem to travel but they don't get delivered. Also, I have 300.000 packets in about 15 seconds for a simple curl to what's my ip. Is This normal ? is there a connection with the fact that I never empty my buffer ? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends on how your code is structured. Once you read and process the data it would probably be appropriate to empty the buffer. But, it really does depend on the data flow.

Comment: Sorry could you explain how to empty the buffer ? also do you think the large number of packets depends on the buffer not being emptied ? also, in my program the flow is continuous, should I cancel the readSource in my case ? Should I use seek ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I checked with Wireshark and I have discovered that my packets do not receive a response. Something in the opposite direction must be broken. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a new question illustrating the problem? It's difficult to answer without seeing how things interrelate.